# How to get json response using Instagram IGTV video url?

Tags: android, json, api, instagram-api

How to download IGTV Video from url using android? My JSON response does not fetch video only contains thumbnail of video but picture can easily get from json response  https://api.instagram.com/oembed/?url= like this how to get video response like this?

Comment: The link doesn't link to the Intagram API. That said, although I don't have much experience in dealing with video, I highly doubt it it'd be sent through a JSON response.

Comment: Do you have any idea about IGTV?

Comment: @k88 when we hit https://api.instagram.com/oembed/?url=myurl so return json response of image but there is no api for video?

Comment: any other way to get video url?

Comment: I am not sure if it is even possible, but I can't comment without seeing the API for it. I tried searching for it, but I am only able to find endpoints for users and comments. https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/